# jquery 1.2.7 how can I replace some text?

Tags: jquery

I cannot upgrade my jQuery, and I was wondering why this function is not existing. How can I implement this:

```
$('#block-block-1 .content').replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,'');
```

What I get is: "function doesn't exist"

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, you want to change the text of that particular element. You can do this using the `.text` method. We use `element.text()` to retrive the text and `element.text(newText)` to set it. We can combine both to alter it.

```
var content = $('#block-block-1 .content');
content.text(content.text().replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,''));
```

If you want to work with multiple elements, you can use the `.each` method to operate on each one separately.

```
$('#block-block-1 .content').each(function(content) {
    content.text(content.text().replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,''));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.replace()` is a member of JavaScript's string object, not a jQuery object. Therefore, you need to get the text of the jQuery object, change it, and update the jQuery object:

```
var content = $('#block-block-1 .content');
var text = content.text();
var replacedText = text.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,'');
content.text(replacedText);
```

Or, using [`text(function(index, text))`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2), a better way:

```
$('#block-block-1 .content').text(function(index, text) {
    return text.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,'');
});
```

#### EDIT:

Darn, the second one's jQuery 1.4 only.

Comment: Didn't know you could use a function in `text`. I'll be remembering that.

Comment: As of 1.4, you can use a function for pretty much everything.